# How to clear a .text or .html before appending new text using an api

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

So I am having an issue of clearing information after inputting a new value. I am using an api that searches for concerts and in some cases when one performer has an event and when searching a different artist does not, the event from the previous call will stay and not clear itself out. I have tried using `empty()` and `clear()` however it doesn't clear do what I am trying to do. This is a sample of the code within the ajax request.

```
let showName = data._embedded.events[0].name;
$("#showName").text(showName);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `#showName` an input or div?

Comment: it is a div. this is the html part that this script is attached to. <div class="is-family-primary has-text-weight-bold is-capitalized title is-spaced" id="showName"></div>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I am not totally clear on what you are asking.  If possible, consider adding a snippet that shows a [mcve] of the issue you are facing-- this will make it much easier for the computer to understand the problem and offer solutions.

Comment: its hard to add a snippet since the information is gathered from the api. so I would need to run a full call request to get the problem to replicate

Comment: but for example, I search Beyonce and the name of the show will display on my page. Then I search for p diddy and because he has not events, the show name will still display Beyonce's event. But when I search another artist that does have an event, then the show name will display the correct information. So what I am trying to do is that when my search button is clicked, it clears the text so that if the next artist search does not have an event it would just be blank.